# What is the best practice/right way to include rxjs store in angular2/4, is it supposed to be in bootstrap or import?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx-store

When I read about ngrx, I see different ways of including the store:

One way I see is to include in imports:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ... omitted
        StoreModule.provideStore(AppReducer),
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

The other way I've seen is to include it in bootstrap:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {App} from './src/app';
import {provideStore} from '@ngrx/store';
import {ItemsService, items, selectedItem} from './src/items';
bootstrap(App, [
  ItemsService, // The actions that consume our store
  provideStore({items, selectedItem}) // The store that defines our app state
])
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Which is correct and/or is the accepted best practice? Why?

I look at a random app.module.ts file from a project without rxjs store and am wondering where it should go properly in a file like this:

```
https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts
```

Appreciate optionally any any references to how "current" May 2017 angular2/4 applications should be organized in respect to integration with RxJS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to keep my AppModule as clean as possible.

One day, while I was thinking a lot about module structure and SPA design with Angular I've seen a [Tweet](https://twitter.com/manekinekko/status/777096554788388864) from Wassim Chegnam. It was about modules with Angular, and he drew this :
[image]

I really liked that idea of having 3 main modules :
 - **features**
 - **shared**
 - **core**

How to use them :

- **Features** for everything directly related to our app
- **Shared** for everything that we want to easily import from everywhere
- **Core** for everything related to the project configuration (mostly modules with `forRoot`)

**So in your case, I'd put the `StoreModule.provideStore(AppReducer)` in `CoreModule`.** ([example](https://github.com/maxime1992/pizza-sync/blob/bb85e1c6f54356bd04c4a559ab2117ad9cf2640b/frontend/src/app/core/core.module.ts#L28))

Obviously, you can go with a simpler module structure but after I used that way of doing things in a [large application](https://gitlab.com/linagora/petals-cockpit) and a small/medium app to demo how to use **ngrx** ([Pizza-Sync](https://github.com/maxime1992/pizza-sync)), it felt like a good thing =).

In the end, I do have an `AppModule` really clean :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and if I need to use angular-universal I'd have no problem to switch from `app.module.ts` to `app.module.universal.ts`.

**Edit: May, 14th (2017)**
I released a couple of days ago an ngrx starter on Github where I try to describe all of that and include a lot of good things I've been discovering for the last 8 months. It might interest some of you: https://github.com/maxime1992/angular-ngrx-starter

Comment: the shared module should be included into feature modules, otherwise there is no difference between core and shared in your picture.

Comment: So if the Store is to be the "database" for the application, what is the difference between "Store" in CoreModule and "Store" in SharedModule? https://gitlab.com/linagora/petals-cockpit/blob/master/frontend/src/app/shared/shared.module.ts Aren't all components in the application going to need the store to be accessible from all features/components of the application?

Comment: My bad, I do not need `StoreModule` in `SharedModule`. Why : `StoreModule` is importing a service and services are available to child modules (even those lazy loaded, unlike components & pipes). So in theory, yes we want to "share" it as we'll be using our store from the whole app. But as we import it from CoreModule using forRoot to pass our root reducer, we do not need to load it one more time in SharedModule. (hope I'm clear).

Comment: @JuliaPassynkova yes SharedModule is made to be used across the app

Comment: I've made an edit to let you know I've build an ngrx starter :) it might help you understand all that!

Answer (score 1):

Following the examples from the ngrx repo, I provide the store under `imports`.

[Example in readme in the ngrx repo:](https://github.com/ngrx/store)

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    StoreModule.provideStore({ counter: counterReducer })
  ]
})
```

The [Official NGRX Example App](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts) also does the same thing.  It puts it under `imports`.

I am not aware of any differences by putting stuff under `bootstrap`, but it seems cleaner to me to separate it out into the `NgModule imports` section.